# Проверка ввода только одного символа

Tags: c++, char, поток-ввода

> Написать программу, печатающую символы от `A` до введенного с клавиатуры символа (последний возможный: `Z`).
>   Для каждого символа вывести номер, сам символ, шестнадцатеричный, восьмеричный и двоичный код этого символа. Предусмотреть обработку ошибок.

В чём нужна помощь: как проверить, если было введено **что угодно, кроме единственного символа `A..Z`** (например, `Aa` - это неверный ввод)? То есть как проверить, лежит ли что-либо в буфере... или, может, более хороший и универсальный подход есть?
Нужна реализация именно с использованием потоков, так как лабораторка основана на этом (вторая часть задания - обработка исключений с использованием `if (!cin)` и т. д., и т. п.).

Мне нужно не очищать поток через `cin.clear()` или `cin.ignore()`, а конкретно заранее проверять, введено ли то, что требуется, и ничего более.

Собственно, имеющийся на данный момент код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char cEnd, cStart;
    int cNo = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "Vvedite simvol ('A' dlya vihoda): ";
        cin >> cEnd;
        if ((cEnd >= 'A') && (cEnd <= 'Z'))
        {
            for (cStart = 'A'; cStart != cEnd + 1; cStart++, cNo++)
            {
                cout << setw(2) << cNo << ' ' << cStart << ' ';
                cout << ios::hex << cStart << ' ';
                cout << ios::oct << cStart << ' ';
                cout << bitset<8>(cStart) << "\n";
            }
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Neverniy vvod\n";
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            continue;
        }
        cNo = 1;
        if (cEnd == 'A')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, вам нужна функция [`peek()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek), которая как раз и смотрит - есть ли что в буфере, и что именно?

Comment: Благодарю, от неё отталкивался и методом "тыка" выяснил, что эта функция возвращает значение `10`, если буфер пуст или же если в нём лежит `\n`...

Comment: В любом случае, этого достаточно, а для исправления я добавлю в код такую проверку: `if ((cEnd >= 'A') && (cEnd <= 'Z') && (cin.peek() == 10))`.